# Expand/Collapse HTML divs simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a row of HTML divs that expand and collapse when you click on them. Please see this jsFiddle to get an idea of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm6Pg/3/. (You may have to expand the result pane or use the full screen result to get all the divs to appear on a single row.)

Currently, I am using [One% CSS Grid](http://onepcssgrid.mattimling.com/) to get all the divs to appear on one row, then toggling different CSS column classes to expand and collapse the divs according to the current state and what div was clicked.

```
<div id="content" class="onepcssgrid-1200">
<div class="onerow">
    <div class="tile col4" id="about">
        <h3>About</h3>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile col4" id="other">
        <h3>Other</h3>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile col4 last" id="stuff">
        <h3>Stuff</h3>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript (I've changed it from what's in the jsFiddle because I was messing around with dynamically determining which column classes needed to be toggled):

```
$(".tile").click(function() {
        var tile = $(this);
        var otherTiles = tile.siblings();
        var currentSelectedTile = otherTiles.filter(".selected");
        var unselectedOtherTiles = otherTiles.not(".selected");
        var otherTileWeight, tileWeight;
        if (currentSelectedTile.length) {
            otherTileWeight = 3;
            tileWeight = 3;
        } else {
            otherTileWeight = 4;
            tileWeight = 4;
        }

        tile.toggleClass("selected col" + tileWeight + " col6", 600);
        currentSelectedTile.toggleClass("selected col3 col4", 600);
        unselectedOtherTiles.toggleClass("col" + otherTileWeight + " col3", 600);
    });
```

This seems like a lot of code that might be wrapped up in a jQuery UI function or some other library that eluded me when I put this together. Is there an easier, more concise, or just plain better way to do this? The solution does not need to use jQuery nor One% CSS Grid, any library is fine. However, it does need to be in a responsive layout that preferably still functions as you'd expect when the divs are on top of each other.